# Probability of a collision between x and x+dx

Tags: probability, probability-theory

I'm studying a probability problem about the mean free path of an air molecule. The book I'm using defines

> prob(x) = probability that the particle travels the distance x
>   without making any collisions

After it the book says

> prob(first collision between x and x+dx) = prob(x) - prob(x+dx)

I really don't get why this is true. For instance, rearranged the terms and wrote it as:

prob(x) = prob(x+dx) + prob(first collision between x and x+dx)

This equation says: the probability that the particle travels x without colliding is equal to the probability that it travels x+dx without colliding plus the probability it makes its first collision between x and x+dx. For me, this makes no sense at all. Can anyone help me make sense of this affirmation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are $3$ events:

- $A = $ it travels $x$ without collision
- $B = $ it travels $x$ without collision and then has a collision within the next $dx$, i.e. in the interval $(x, x+dx)$.  This is equivalent to "first collision between $x$ and $x+dx$".
- $C = $ it travels $x$ without collision and then further travels $dx$ without collision.  This is equivalent to "it travels $x+dx$ without collision".

Note that $A = B \cup C$ and $B \cap C = \emptyset$.  Therefore $P(A) = P(B) + P(C)$.

Comment: Could you please clarify?

Comment: Does the edit make it clear enough?